Why does the computer account not match in NPS RADIUS certificate authentication, but a user account does?
I am configuring a standalone Windows Server 2022 setup with the following roles:
Active Directory
Certificate Authority
Network Policy Server (NPS)
I am using this server as a RADIUS server to authenticate a Wi-Fi network with an Aruba Access Point (cloud-managed). Here is what I’ve done so far:

Steps I’ve Taken:

Basic RADIUS Authentication with Local User:

I created a local user account (ABC) on the server.
Configured the Aruba Access Point to use the server as a RADIUS server.
Successfully connected a non-domain-joined Windows 11 client to the Wi-Fi using the local user credentials.

Switching to Certificate-Based Authentication:

Created a computer account named computer01 in Active Directory.
Issued a client authentication certificate for computer01 and installed it on the client.
Installed the CA certificate on the client.
Renamed the client machine to computer01 and configured the Wi-Fi profile to use computer authentication.

Encountered Issues:

In the NPS logs, the connection was denied because the account was not found. The log showed the username as host/computer01.
To troubleshoot, I modified the NPS server to:
Strip the host/ prefix.
Append @mydomain.local to the username.
Deleted the computer01 computer account and created a user account with the same name (computer01).
Issued a new client authentication certificate for the user account and installed it on the client.

Results:

The user account (computer01) was matched, but authentication still failed with a certificate-related error.

My Questions:

Why does the computer account (host/computer01) not match during authentication, but the user account (computer01) does?

What name should be used in the certificate to ensure successful authentication?



What I’ve Tried:
Adjusted the NPS policies to manipulate the username (host/computer01 → computer01@mydomain.local).
Issued certificates with the following configurations:
For the computer account: Common Name (CN) = computer01.
For the user account: Common Name (CN) = computer01.
Installed the certificates on the client and ensured the CA certificate was trusted.
Verified that the Wi-Fi profile was set to use computer authentication.

Environment Details:
Server: Windows Server 2022 with AD, CA, and NPS roles.
Client: Windows 11, non-domain-joined.
Authentication: EAP-TLS with certificate-based authentication.
Access Point: Aruba (cloud-managed).

NPS Event Log Observations:

When Using the Computer Account (host/computer01):

The log shows "Access Denied" with the reason: "Account not found."
The username appears in the format: host/computer01.

When Using the User Account (computer01):

The account is found, but authentication fails due to a certificate mismatch.

Suspected Issues:

Certificate Mapping:

The NPS server may not correctly map the certificate to the computer account due to the host/ prefix or differences in how computer accounts and user accounts are handled.

Certificate Configuration:

The certificate issued for the computer account might not have the correct subject or Subject Alternative Name (SAN) required for authentication.

NPS Policy Configuration:

The NPS policy may expect a specific format for the username or certificate attributes, such as a UPN (e.g., computer01@mydomain.local) rather than host/computer01.

What I Need:

Clarification on Certificate Requirements:

Should the certificate's Common Name (CN) or Subject Alternative Name (SAN) match the computer account's UPN or SAMAccountName?
For a computer account, what should the certificate's subject and SAN look like?

Guidance on NPS Configuration:

How can I ensure the NPS server correctly maps the certificate to the computer account?
Should the NPS policy strip the host/ prefix, or is there a better approach?
